# Send the change date into the next page URL PHP HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image]I am new to PHP and HTML and trying the below.  The below html code displays data from the database and add a calendar as row. The calendar displays current date by default. When changed, the changed date should be passed in the url.

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    ?>
    
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Update Clients</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container my-5">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Start Date</th>
                        <th scope="col">Interest</th>
                        <th scope="col">Date</th>
                        <th scope="col">Days</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT id, name, DATE_FORMAT(startDate, '%Y-%m-%d') AS startDate, interest, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM clientdata c WHERE clientId = id) AS days
                    FROM `clients` WHERE now() BETWEEN startdate and enddate ORDER BY id";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                    if ($result) {
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $id = $row['id'];
                            $name = $row['name'];
                            $startdate = $row['startDate'];
                            $interest = $row['interest'];
                            $days = $row['days'];
                            $todaydate = date("Y-m-d");
                            echo ' <tr>
                            <th scope="row">' . $id . '</th>
                            <td>' . $name . '</td>
                            <td>' . $startdate . '</td>
                            <td>' . $interest . '</td>
                            <td> <input type="date" id = "changeDate" value=' . $todaydate . '></input></td>
                            <td>' . $days . '</td>
                            <td> 
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" onchange="myFunction()"><a href="insertClientData.php?id='.$id.'&name='.$name.'&todaydate='. $todaydate .'" class="text-light"> Update </a></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="container my-5">
            <table> <tr>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary my-3"><a href="main.php" class="text-light"> Home Page </a></button>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Need to display the today's date into the date field and when click on the update URL needs to find the new selected date. The update button should be passed with the selected date

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onchange="myFunction()"><a href="insertClientData.php?id=.$id.&name=.$name.&todaydate=. $todaydate" class="text-light"> Update </a></button>
```

Comment: **Question**: what does the "insertClientData.php" do ? (insert ? / update ?) -- I suppose is an update operation, if that is the case, which data field will be updated ?

Comment: Although it says update, I am inserting the data.  I just pick the id, name and date field and insert into another table. @KenLee

Comment: I assume that you will insert a record into [ClientData] table, setting id=$Id, name=$name and todaydate=[picked_date] ? (please correct me if my assumption is wrong) -- these details are needed for me (or other volunteers) to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: exactly @KenLee. thats what i want to do. if not selected, the current date should be picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want to call a PHP (insertClientData.php) by GET, I have removed the PHP code and give you an example in pure HTML and JS. (after understanding the code you can amend it by adding the PHP statements)

The trick is to use jquery `closest` and `find` to locate the row's data thru the `classes` (in this case, xid, xname and changeDate) and then do a call to the PHP by `window.location.href`

So the code is

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table border=1> 
<tr>
<th class=xid scope="row">123</th>
<td class=xname>Mary Roberson</td>
<td><input type="date" class = "changeDate" value='2022-11-22'></input></td>
<td>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</td>

<tr>
<th class=xid scope="row">333</th>
<td class=xname>Peter Pen</td>
<td><input type="date" class = "changeDate" value='2022-11-22'></input></td>
<td>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</td>

</table>


<script>
$('.btn-primary').click(function(){

  var xdate=($(this).closest('tr').find('.changeDate').val());
  var xid=($(this).closest('tr').find('.xid').text());
  var xname=($(this).closest('tr').find('.xname').text());

  window.location.href="insertClientData.php?id="+ xid+ "&name="+ xname+ "&todaydate="+ xdate;
});
</script>
```

Please try it and then you will find that it should work as expected, then you may amend it by adding PHP statements into the appropriate places

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose each row within a form element with a method of "GET" when you submit the form, the parameters will be encoded to the page and the variable will be accessible via the url parameters.

I am not sure why you have attempted to incorporate a href link within the bottom. If you want to pass other information in the URL you can use hidden input fields to automatically populate within your loop.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Update Clients</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container my-5">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">id</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Start Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Interest</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Days</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
      $sql = "SELECT id, name, DATE_FORMAT(startDate, '%Y-%m-%d') AS startDate, interest, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM clientdata c WHERE clientId = id) AS days
                    FROM `clients` WHERE now() BETWEEN startdate and enddate ORDER BY id";
      $result = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );
      if ( $result ) {
          while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
              $id = $row[ 'id' ];
              $name = $row[ 'name' ];
              $startdate = $row[ 'startDate' ];
              $interest = $row[ 'interest' ];
              $days = $row[ 'days' ];
              $todaydate = date( "Y-m-d" );
              echo ' 
                    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="get">
                    <tr>
                            <th scope="row">' . $id . '</th>
                            <td>' . $name . '</td>
                            <td>' . $startdate . '</td>
                            <td>' . $interest . '</td>
                            <td> <input type="date" id = "changeDate" value=' . $todaydate . '></input></td>
                            <td>' . $days . '</td>
                            <td> 
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
                            </td>
                     </tr>
                     </form>
                     ';
          }
      }
      ?>
        <br>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="container my-5">
<table>
<tr>
  <button class="btn btn-primary my-3">
  <a href="main.php" class="text-light"> Home Page </a>
  </button>
```